# Creating a Snowflake warehouse in a stored procedure changes the current warehouse

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a procedure that creates users, roles and warhouse. This procedure is executed with a high privilege user with ACCOUNTADMIN role

```
USE ACCOUNT_ADMIN;
USE WAREHOUSE PROVISIONER;

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE TEST()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  AS
  $$
    snowflake.execute({ sqlText: "CREATE OR REPLACE WAREHOUSE test;"});
    return "";
  $$
;
```

Now if I query the current warehouse:

```
SELECT CURRENT_WAREHOUSE();
```

I get `PROVISIONER`

If I now call the procedure

```
CALL TEST();
```

The warehouse has changed

```
SELECT CURRENT_WAREHOUSE();
```

Now returns `TEST`

Is this the normal behaviour? This is an issue because the warehouse is changed outside of the procedure, and I cannot use the "USE WAREHOUSE" statement inside a procedure.

Is there another way to create WAREHOUSE from a procedure without changing the current warehouse?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected. See [the docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#session-state) for background information.

One way to work around it would be to get the current warehouse at the beginning of your stored procedure, and set it again as the current one at the end of the stored procedure.

Comment: In my tests, this also happens when I create a warehouse directly, without a procedure.

Comment: Yes, creating warehouses and databases/schemas always also sets them as current.

Comment: That's good to know but it's not documented, that I can see.  Not to split hairs.

Comment: Thanks this issue is that the “USE warehouse” is not allowed in a stored procedure, so I cannot change the current warehouse back to what is was before.